# Subclassing DatagridView, onPaint event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am subclassing DataGridView to extend and bind some common functionailty.
Here I overrides few (about 10) events and everything work OK except onPaint event.

Code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class xDataGridView
Inherits DataGridView

Private _selected_row As Integer
Protected Overrides Sub onPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    sel_row = Me.CurrentRow.Index + 1
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub

<Browsable(True)> _
Public Property sel_row() As Integer
    Get
        Return _selected_row
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        _selected_row = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

In main form which contains this class under _Paint event handler I would like to get selected row as common property: mySel_row = myDGV.sel_row
When I try to open designer for main form in VBIDE on place of DGV is big red 'X' with red border.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But if I start a program it works normally.
All other events from this class also work normally and doesn't report that.

What may be a cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the current row for the datagridview in design view is probably null. That's what's causing the System.NullReferenceException, and if you read the message box that comes up and tells you the error, it probably says the error is on this line: `sel_row = Me.CurrentRow.Index + 1`. One way you could fix this problem would be to do something like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub onPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    If (Not IsNothing(Me.CurrentRow)) Then sel_row = Me.CurrentRow.Index + 1
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

I pasted the code that you posted and got the error you did, and adding this conditional statement to check if the current row is null keeps the exception from being thrown when you're in design view. (You'll have to build the project to get rid of the error message that's in the control.) HTH

Comment: Exactly as you assumed, that's it. Now works without any error. Thank you.